# mod_rewrite works on linux, but not on windows

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

This rule works well on Linux based machine:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

But on windows based it doesn't. Maybe there is another way to make it work on both systems?

Comment: The mod_rewrite module in xampp server is disabled by default. search and activate it (remove #) in apache/conf/httpd.conf then restart the apache server.

Comment: It's activated, and i thinking the best idea is just change rule...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "it doesn't work" on Windows? I'm pretty sure this is an issue with `mod_rewrite` working on your windows setup, and has nothing to do with this particular rule. I'm guessing if you look at [`apache_get_modules()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php), you'll see it is not listed.

Comment: Well, it doesn't, tryed WampServer and xampp. Evene http://localhost/images or http://localhost/javascript or others folders. If i remove that rule from .htaccess everythink works...

Answer (score 0):

It's not depend on OS. I think you used Apache on Linux and now using IIS.

htaccess for IIS is explained here : http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/